# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class rak implements Serializable{

    int i;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // write your code herer
        rak r = new rak();
        r.i = 9;

        File f = new File("da.txt");
        FileOutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(f1);
        oos.writeObject("value of  i is" + r.i);

        FileInputStream f0 = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream f9 = new ObjectInputStream(f0);
        rak r1 = new rak();
        r1 = (rak) f9.readObject();

        System.out.println(r1.i);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider asking a real question, and describing which exact errors you get and from which lines.

Comment: Ok sorry error on line number 23 r1=(rak) f9.readObject();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line:

```
oos.writeObject("value of  i is" + r.i);
```

You serialize the String `"value of  i is9"` literally instead of the object itself. Thus the only possible cast is to the String again.

```
String string = (String) f9.readObject();
```

To fix this issue, serialize the whole object:

```
rak r = new rak();
r.i = 9;
// ...
oos.writeObject(r);
```

And the result of the last line would be correct:

```
// ...
rak r1 =  (rak) f9.readObject();
System.out.println(r1.i);          // prints 9
```

Comment: Please, mark the best answer as accepted to let others know this issue has been resolved.

Comment: The same thing worked for my friend who used netbeans ide for debugging....
How is that possible?

Comment: And how to mark the best answer...I am new to stack overflow...I am newbie

Comment: You choose the best one and click to the “mark” symbol on the left side of the answer. It will change color to green. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You serialize a `String` :

```
rak r = new rak();
...
oos.writeObject("value of  i is" + r.i);
```

And you cast the deserialization result into a `rak` object :

```
r1 = (rak) f9.readObject();
```

Whereas the `ClassCastException` : a `String` is not a `rak`.

If you want to deserialize a `rak`, serialize it and not only one of its fields such as :

```
oos.writeObject(r);
```